# Reversing a hash and merging keys in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, key, reverse, key-value

My hash is:

```
h = { 'a' => ['x' ,'y'], 'b' => ['x','z']}
```

I want to reverse the keys and values and merge the new keys in a way which will result in

```
 res = { 'x' => ['a','b'], 'y' => ['a'], 'z' => ['b']}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: think that people will try to use your example to test, give a hash with values, not variables or placeholders.

Comment: edited it so it would use strings, I think its better than using more complex objects

Comment: Ok, it may also help to show some code to see where you are at. I guess you have working code but not satisfied with the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = {}
h.each{|k, v| v.each{|vv| res[vv] ||= []; res[vv].push(k)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Functional approach using [Enumerable#map_by](http://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#map_by-instance_method) from Facets:

```
require 'facets'
h.flat_map { |k, vs| vs.product([k]) }.map_by { |k, v| [k, v] }
#=> {"x"=>["a", "b"], "y"=>["a"], "z"=>["b"]}
```

Comment: any idea why I am getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'map_by' for [["x", "a"], ["y", "a"], ["x", "b"], ["z", "b"]]:Array`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
rev = {}
h.collect{|k, v| v.each{|vv| rev.has_key?(vv)? rev[vv] << k : (rev[vv] = [k])}}
```

I tested it, it is working.